# Change home page to blog.php and add another home page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress installation on my website. Now I need to create a landing page (not WordPress) and, at the same time, maintain the WordPress installation on the same folder and still being able to access it with a different URL (e.g. www.mysite.com/blog.php instead of www.mysite.com).

So, to sum up:

- index.php should be changed to blog.php
- In this way, I can add a landing page (index.html) to my website
- When accessing the website I should see the landing page (index.html), but still be able to see WordPress at www.mysite.com/blog.php (so, maintaining also the old permalinks to the blog)

I guess I should be changing the .htaccess file and maybe the settings of the blog, but I'm not able to find anything on the web (probably, I don't know what to look for).

Comment: changing index.php to blog.php is a VERY bad idea, it means changing the Wordpress core files and you will broke everything and you will no more be able to keep the site working

Answer (score 0):

By default server show `index.html` file first. you should not create a `blog.php` page. if in a directory has two files `index.html` and `index.php` you will see `index.html` when you visit your site.
just create an `index.html` page it will automatically show at first.
and if it not works .. just backup your `.htaccess` and delete it until you are working on developing.
That's it.